# @types included in 'typeRoots' but only working if explicitly included

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm attempting to use the grecaptcha types package (`@types/grecaptcha`), but even though in my `tsconfig`, its setup as:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
```

When I try to utilize the included `grecaptcha` object or `RecaptchaV2`, I get errors on compile:

```
Cannot find namespace 'ReCaptchaV2'
Cannot find name 'grecaptcha'
```

If I explicitly include `/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/@types/grecaptcha/index.d.ts" />` to the top of my file, it works, but from all I can tell, I shouldn't have to do this.

It was suggested I check `tsc --listFiles`, and the type files show up there. I'd love any additional advice on figuring out what's going on and correcting it.

I'm building an Angular project, and as I'm using angular-cli, I'm running typescript 2.4.2 if it matters.

Comment: Is there any particular IDE you are using, or are you just calling `tsc` directly? If you are using the TypeScript compiler directly, I recommend _not_ using `typeRoots`, in which case it will already include `node_modules/@types`. If you are using an IDE, I wonder if it is doing something funky.

Comment: @Fenton I'm using VSCode, which doesn't recognize it without the explicit typing, but the errors show up on compilation as well. I'm using `typeRoots` as that was setup by `angular-cli`; I'm wondering why I'm having so much trouble when other's don't?

Comment: Can you post a short version of a problem file (the one where you added the reference comments, for example).

Comment: @Fenton https://gist.github.com/rohitsodhia/8d8cd18801912e7712fba691a74a6b18 You can see I try to reference `grecaptcha` and `Recaptchav2` a few times. Without the reference at the top, I get the errors mentioned. With it, it's fine. I don't know if that's exactly what you were asking for.

Comment: But I was under the impression that the typeRoots value in the tsconfig told the compiler to include everything listed under it, negating the need to manually include.

Comment: I'll have to replicate your project in VSCode... see what I get.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and it is working fine now.

```json
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["grecaptcha"],
```